# Order data by row names in a dataframe

Tags: r

I am working with a data frame. I would like to order the data frame by its rownames.

I tried using the sort function

```
sort(mydataframe$rownames, pattern="Lung", full.names = TRUE)
```

This is the data frame that I am working with:

```
     input filtered denoisedF denoised merged nonchim
Lung 41229    39034     38724    38088  37693   37693
Oral 36891    33654     33276    32474  29641   28513
Lung 15366    14201     13564    10355   7820    7815
.
.
.
```

My expected output is something like this:

```
     input filtered denoisedF denoised merged nonchim
Lung 41229    39034     38724    38088  37693   37693
Lung 15366    14201     13564    10355   7820    7815
Oral 36891    33654     33276    32474  29641   28513
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `tidyverse`, I would do the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  arrange(rowname)
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to figure it out using something similar to this